# Django - Heroku - debug error 500 when deleting an object in Prod

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-models, django-views

Problem:

- Server Error 500 when trying to delete a user account in Prod.

Scenarios:

- Delete a user account in Dev - works fine
- Create a user account in Prod - works fine
- Delete a user account in Prod - error 500

view.py:

```
@login_required 
def account_destroy_view(request, id=None, *args, **kwargs):   
  try:
    obj = request.user   
  except request.user.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404   
  if request.method == "POST":
    try:
      customer = StripeRecord.objects.get(user_id=obj.id)
      stripe.api_key = config('STRIPE_API_KEY')
      stripe.Customer.delete(customer.stripe_customer_id)
    except StripeRecord.DoesNotExist:
      pass
    obj.delete()
    return redirect("/")
  return render(request, "accounts/delete.html", {"object": obj})
```

accounts model.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

stripe model.py:

```
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class StripeRecord(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  ...
```

Heroku log:

```
Sep 23 19:37:37 weatherapp app/web.1 10.1.24.136 - - [24/Sep/2021:02:37:36 +0000] "POST /delete/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "https://www.weatherapp.com/delete/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36 Edg/93.0.961.52"
```

What I've tried & questions:

- I've checked Stripe logs, the object has been deleted on Stripe. So the issue isn't on the Stripe env var or integration.
- Tried to delete a user account directly using Django admin tool in Prod - still error 500. I suspect it's because I created the model with AbstractUser and it is a foreignkey to another model?
- How to get more details on the error? ( `heroku logs --tail` only returns what I've shown above )

Comment: "How to get more details on the error?"—either by adding some logging to your `account_destroy_view` view function or by turning on debug mode and using whatever tools you like to use in development mode (unless that's what you mean by "dev" vs. "prod").

Comment: Thanks @Chris I've checked the logs in sentry and after some debugging, I noticed one of the tables didn't generate primary key in Prod. I must have missed a migration at some point and messed up the DB!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StripeRecord table missing primary key in Prod because I missed a migration after making changes on the model.

The problem was resolved after resetting the Prod DB (luckily it's a personal project).